# How to generalize standard deviation for n-dimensional arrays?

Tags: standard-deviation

**Here is the application:** I have a spectrometer and I need to test different lighting setups for it. Each time, I illuminate a fixed set of 9 color references, and I measure them. The spectrometer is sensible to 8 wavelengths. Here are the plots with two different configurations:

- Configuration #1

[image]

- Configuration #2

[image]

As you can see, configuration #1 gives less scattered data than configuration #2.

My goal is to choose the configuration where *the data are the most scattered*, so that it will be easier for me to differentiate the colors.

Thus I need to have a metrics to compare the configuration between them. Something like standard deviation would do, but I do not know how to generalize it to arrays. Is there a better solution?

Thank you for your advices. :)

Comment: Hello, could you simply compute the covariance matrix (whose elements are the covariance of each pair of coordinates) and take a (matrix) square root ?

Comment: "Need metrics to choose the configurations which is the less scattered" is so general and abstract that it invites many possible potentially conflicting answers.  Could you perhaps explain what you mean by "scattered"?

Comment: I have updated my question to be more specific. Is it more clear now? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider

1. Normalizing the spectrum vectors so that their 7-entry light intensity vectors are all unit vectors in $L_2$ sense.
2. Use the angle between each vector pair as a measure of their distance.